# MapFragment in Fragment, alternatives?

Tags: android, fragment, google-maps-android-api-2, mapfragment

I need your help... I work on it until 3 days. My app is working with fragments.
One of these fragments has to display a map from the Google Maps V2 api for Android.

Currently, I'm using a MapFragment, but no surprise, a fragment in a fragment is not a good idea, but it works, the map is displaying, i can edit it but when I switch of main fragment and return on it.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #59: Duplicate id 0x7f070041, tag null, or parent id 0x7f070040 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
>
> at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4252)
>
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)

This is the cause when I go on another fragment and return to the one which contains the map.
I'm searching until 3 days to fix this but no great results.

To resume for you, I've an Activity which calls a fragment which contains a MapFragment in the layout file.
If you need more, just ask :)

Thanks

Edit :
Here is the code to change Fragment in the main Activity

```
private void swtichFragment(Fragment fragment, Bundle bundle)
{
fragment.setBundle(this, bundle);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.rightFragmentPlaceHolder, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
mRightFragment = fragment;
}
```

Comment: show your fragment switching code...

Comment: Added the function to switch fragment :)

Comment: Are you holding the map as a reference in a static way or have you passed it to some other class that may have it still alive?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use MapView instead of MapFragment in your Fragment's layout. Remember to call MapView's lifecycle methods:

- onCreate(Bundle)
- onResume()
- onPause()
- onDestroy()
- onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)
- onLowMemory()

as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView).

Btw. you shouldn't be using MapFragment, only SupportMapFragment and [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html).

**Edit:**

If you switch to support library, you can use code from comment #1 here:
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5064#c1

Comment: Out of interest, why shouldn't we be using MapFragment?

Comment: @JamesMundy One reason could be that support library contains `Fragment`s that are likely to be less buggy than native ones on early versions of Android 4.x, so even if you are targeting only 4.x, you use less buggy code for a little price of few hundred kB in your APK. Another thing, if client finally decides that you still need to support 2.3.3, you have less work.

Answer (score 43):

Use SupportMapFragment to overcome this error:

**In fragment layout**

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/googleMap"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**In Your Fragment onCreateView**

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);

        if (mapFragment != null) {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }
```

Since your layout is in the `Fragment's` layout, therefore the `SupportMapFragment` is the child layout of your fragment. Hence use `getChildFragmentManager()` which is `Fragment's FragmentManager`

Comment: This is the best way to go hands-down. This changes one line of code from the Google Sample and makes it work. Well done Adnan

Comment: Thanks for explaining getChildFragmentManager(). That did the trick for me

Answer (score 13):

[As described here](http://kyuritsolution.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-display-mapfragment-inside.html)

To display MapFragment inside the fragment(NestedFragment):
At this point I believe you have

1. added necessary permission on manifest
2. added google play service as a lib project
3. api key in manifest file.
   4.

where.xml

```
 <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
         <FrameLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1.03"
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
           android:id="@+id/mapwhere" />


          <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

class:

```
 public class WhereFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

    @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
      super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
      View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.where, null, false); 
      initilizeMap();
      return root;
     }

    private void initilizeMap()
     {
      mSupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapwhere);
      if (mSupportMapFragment == null) {
       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
       FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
       mSupportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
       fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mapwhere, mSupportMapFragment).commit();
         }
      if (mSupportMapFragment != null)
      {
       googleMap = mSupportMapFragment.getMap();
       if (googleMap != null)
        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener()
        {
         @Override
         public void onMapClick(LatLng point)
         {
          //TODO: your onclick stuffs
         }
        });
      }
     }
    }
```

*Documentation*:

> Nested Fragments You can now embed fragments inside fragments. This is
>   useful for a variety of situations in which you want to place dynamic
>   and re-usable UI components into a UI component that is itself dynamic
>   and re-usable. For example, if you use ViewPager to create fragments
>   that swipe left and right and consume a majority of the screen space,
>   you can now insert fragments into each fragment page.
>
> To nest a fragment, simply call getChildFragmentManager() on the
>   Fragment in which you want to add a fragment. This returns a
>   FragmentManager that you can use like you normally do from the
>   top-level activity to create fragment transactions. For example,
>   here’s some code that adds a fragment from within an existing Fragment
>   class:
>
> Fragment videoFragment = new VideoPlayerFragment();
>   FragmentTransaction transaction =
>   getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
>   transaction.add(R.id.video_fragment, videoFragment).commit(); From
>   within a nested fragment, you can get a reference to the parent
>   fragment by calling getParentFragment().
>
> The Android Support Library also now supports nested fragments, so you
>   can implement nested fragment designs on Android 1.6 and higher.
>
> Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout
>   includes a . Nested fragments are only supported when added
>   to a fragment dynamically.

*source:http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments*

*This will also fix for:*

```
 11-06 11:36:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6309): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-06 11:36:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6309): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
    11-06 11:36:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
    11-06 11:36:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
    11-06 11:36:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
    11-06 11:36:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
    11-06 11:36:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
    11-06 11:36:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
    11-06 11:36:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
    11-06 11:36:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    11-06 11:36:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6309):  at com.abc.android.ui.WhereFragment.onCreateView(WhereFragment.java:60)
    11-06 11:36:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6309):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
    11-06 11:36:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6309):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
    11-06 11:36:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6309):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
    11-06 11:36:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6309):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    11-06 11:36:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6309):  at a ...
```

Comment: Hi Here I am getting googlemap instance null.. Can You pls help me to resolve this.

Comment: Worked fine to keep the map fragment live in a tab or navigation drawer with other fragments, thanks

Answer (score 5):

### In Your Class

```
      SupportMapFragment mSupportMapFragment;
      private GoogleMap googleMap;
      int ZOOM_LEVEL=15;

      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View mTrackView = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.mylayout, container, false);
        mSupportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mapwhere, mSupportMapFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        return mTrackView;
    }

      @Override
      public void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          super.onStart();

        if(mSupportMapFragment!=null){

            googleMap = mSupportMapFragment.getMap();
            if(googleMap!=null){
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);


            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(12.12122,
                        17.22323), ZOOM_LEVEL);
            googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
              }
            }
      }
```

### mylayout.xml

```
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
     <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1.03"

       android:id="@+id/mapwhere" />


      <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **layout file**

```
<fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

In your **fragment** `onCreate()`, reference the **map fragment** in your **fragment layout file** using `childFragmentManager`

```
// Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment: SupportMapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        // Set callback on the fragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

After lot of mistakes I finally made it , here is my MapView Fragment Class   :-

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.serveroverload.yago.R;

/**
 * @author 663918
 *
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener {
    // Class to do operations on the Map
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public static Fragment newInstance() {
        return new HomeFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
        Bundle bdl = getArguments();

        // setuping locatiomanager to perfrom location related operations
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Requesting locationmanager for location updates
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 1, this);

        // To get map from MapFragment from layout
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        // To change the map type to Satellite
        // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

        // To show our current location in the map with dot
        // googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // To listen action whenever we click on the map
        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                /*
                 * LatLng:Class will give us selected position lattigude and
                 * longitude values
                 */
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), latLng.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        changeMapMode(3);

        // googleMap.setSatellite(true);
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        return v;
    }

    private void doZoom() {
        if (googleMap != null) {
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(18.520430, 73.856744), 17));
        }
    }

    private void changeMapMode(int mapMode) {

        if (googleMap != null) {
            switch (mapMode) {
            case 0:
                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
                break;

            case 1:
                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                break;

            case 2:
                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                break;

            case 3:
                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
                break;

            case 4:
                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void createMarker(double latitude, double longitude) {
        // double latitude = 17.385044;
        // double longitude = 78.486671;

        // lets place some 10 random markers
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // random latitude and logitude
            double[] randomLocation = createRandLocation(latitude, longitude);

            // Adding a marker
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(randomLocation[0], randomLocation[1])).title(
                    "Hello Maps " + i);

            Log.e("Random", "> " + randomLocation[0] + ", " + randomLocation[1]);

            // changing marker color
            if (i == 0)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
            if (i == 1)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
            if (i == 2)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN));
            if (i == 3)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            if (i == 4)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            if (i == 5)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
            if (i == 6)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            if (i == 7)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));
            if (i == 8)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET));
            if (i == 9)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));

            googleMap.addMarker(marker);

            // Move the camera to last position with a zoom level
            if (i == 9) {
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(randomLocation[0], randomLocation[1]))
                        .zoom(15).build();

                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            }
        }

    }

    /*
     * creating random postion around a location for testing purpose only
     */
    private double[] createRandLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {

        return new double[] { latitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                longitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                150 + ((Math.random() - 0.5) * 10) };
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (null != googleMap) {
            // To get lattitude value from location object
            double latti = location.getLatitude();
            // To get longitude value from location object
            double longi = location.getLongitude();

            // To hold lattitude and longitude values
            LatLng position = new LatLng(latti, longi);

            createMarker(latti, longi);

            // Creating object to pass our current location to the map
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            // To store current location in the markeroptions object
            markerOptions.position(position);

            // Zooming to our current location with zoom level 17.0f
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position,
                    17f));

            // adding markeroptions class object to the map to show our current
            // location in the map with help of default marker
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroyView();

        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

        android.app.Fragment fragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (null != fragment) {
            android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity()
                    .getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }


}
```

My Xml file looks like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And result looks like this :-

[image]

**Most Important thing to note is that DO Not Mix app.Fragment with v4.Fragments else app will crash badly.**

As you can see I have used app.Fragment to attach and remove my MapView Fragment

Hope it will help Somebody

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the MapFragment inside of a `FragmentContainerView` from `androidx` `Fragment` package:

- [FragmentContainerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentContainerView)
- From: `implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:$1.2.4"`
- Check: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment

Answer (score 0):

```
            <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:id="@+id/location_map"
            android:layout_above="@id/atmLocation_recyclerView"
            />


View root= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a_t_m_locations, container, false);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.location_map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(googleMap -> {
        mMap=googleMap;
        if(mMap!=null){
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        }
    });
```