# Tabhost/Tabspec, SupportMapFragment with custom layout, will this solution work?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-tabhost, supportmapfragment

There are lots of people that have had problems having the new v2 mapfragment in tab layouts - the map wont draw, or the app craches when tabbing away and back. (examples here: [Error opening SupportMapFragment for second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565460/error-opening-supportmapfragment-for-second-time) and here: [MapFragment in Fragment, alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433820/mapfragment-in-fragment-alternatives?lq=1))

The solutions i've seen won't work so well for me, however, since i want a couple of tabs in the bottom, and in my map-tab, i want dropdowns, buttons and some other fancy stuff on top of the map, within the tab.

After some tinkering, I came up with a solution that seems to work ok, but i haven't seen it mentioned anywhere else, and i do feel it's a bit on the 'hacky' side, so i'm reaching out for validation :)

1.. I have a layout.xml (called R.layout.map below) that describes my buttons, dropdowns etc. with no reference to any map at all (unlike most other solutions that have the map fragment defined in the xml).

2.. My MainActivity has the usual tabhost/tabspec routine to switch between fragments as detailed in lots of places:

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();
    addTab(this, tabHost, "home", R.string.label_tab_home, R.drawable.but_flag, MainFragment.class);
    addTab(this, tabHost, "map", R.string.label_tab_map, R.drawable.but_globe, MapFragment.class);
```

.....

```
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
```

3.. In my MapFragment, i extend SupportMapFragment rather than Fragment and do some funky stuff to get my layout on top. Basically, i cast the SupportMapFragment class to a layout, so that i can add my layout as a subview. /

```
public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment{
...
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FrameLayout mapView = (FrameLayout)super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout mapcomponents = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);
    mapView.addView(mapcomponents);
    return mapView;
}
```

I have tried this on a couple of phones for a while and it does seem to work. And yeah, i do need to support 2.1.

The code i'm worried about is, not surprisingly perhaps, casting the View returned from SupportMapFragment's oncreateview to a FrameLayout, so that i can add my "components"-layout to it.

Are there any problems doing it this way? Is there another way to add the view that i've missed?

Thoughts appreciated.

Comment: `TabActivity` -- the presumed base class for this implementation -- has been deprecated for over two years.

Comment: I'm not using a TabActivity, what led you to believe that? I'm using TabWidget with some custom layouts and classes, with fragments within each tab.

Comment: My apologies. I saw that you were passing Java `.class` objects to an `addTab()` method and thought that you were using the form of `TabSpec` that takes an `Intent`, which in turn requires `TabActivity` (or some other `ActivityGroup`) as the base class. All that being said, you might want to consider alternative tab solutions, such as `FragmentTabHost`, `ViewPager` and a tab-style indicator, or action bar tabs. Any of those will be more natural for use with fragments than is `TabHost`.

Comment: Heh, well its perhaps a bit off-topic, but i wanted to have the same look and feel for my app both in android and IOS, which meant having tabs in the bottom, and make them look slightly different than the standard one. I experimented alot, tried different stuff, but ended up with a solution much like the one in this post: http://adilsoomro.blogspot.se/2011/06/iphone-like-tabs-in-android.html

Comment: "which meant having tabs in the bottom" -- don't use bottom tab bars: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html Few people care whether your iOS and Android apps look the same, because few people will ever *see* both the iOS and Android apps. Your objective should be to provide a UX that is natural for the platform. Would you write an iOS app that didn't offer navigation, because Android devices have a BACK button, and you wanted "the same look and feel for [your] app both in android and IOS"?

Comment: @Commonsware I am aware of that page. But sometimes, things are not in your hands. I'm sure you've been in that situation at one point or another. Having said that, i don't think your example is fair. Bottom tabs is is pretty common in lots of places and something most people wont feel is unnatural, regardless of platform. Its not exactly specific to IOS.

Comment: You are welcome to your opinion. My opinion simply is that anyone who wants "to have the same look and feel for my app both in android and IOS" isn't thinking the issues through. Your comment here suggests that it is some client of yours that is not thinking things through, in which case *they* need to read that page, and http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/08/tips-for-android-tabs.html. In the end, Google does not enforce its UI guidelines the way Apple does, so you can do what you want. However, if you follow Apple's UI guidelines, why wouldn't you do the same for Google's?

Comment: Not disagreeing mate. My only point is that bottom tabs isnt such a big deal, in my mind, and that your example is much more serious. On this topic, i find the tabbing function in apps on android pretty interesting. Maaan, have we got lots of different ways different major app producers have solved it...