# MapFragment and the dreaded "Duplicate id" exception - how to use MapFragment in an AlertDialog

Tags: android, fragment, mapfragment

So, I have the error described in this post:

- [Duplicate ID, tag null, or parent id with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083950/duplicate-id-tag-null-or-parent-id-with-another-fragment-for-com-google-androi)

I have searched SO and found several explainations on why I get this error:

- http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments
- [MapFragment in Fragment, alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433820/mapfragment-in-fragment-alternatives)

and so on.

My problem is that I think I dont fully understand how Fragments are to be used (yes, I have read the part on Fragments on the Android dev sites), and more specifically, how to solve my specific problem.

I have a fragment called "BookingList". That BookingList has rows with bookings, and each row can be clicked. When I click, I show a Dialog with some info about that booking, and a map. The list is a ListView and the onClickListener is like this:

```
public class BookingList extends Fragment {

// ... code code code

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
       // ... code

       // ... code

       list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
       {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
          {
              BookingLight bl = (BookingLight)bookingRowAdapter.getRow(position);
              String name = bl.Customer.Firstname + " " + bl.Customer.Lastname;
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Öppnar " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              Handler myHandler = new Handler(); 
              myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
              {
                  @Override
                  public void run()
                  {
                      View detailsView = infl.inflate(R.layout.booking_details, null);
                      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                      builder.setView(detailsView);
                      builder.create().show();
                  }
              }, 500);
          }
      });
```

As you can see, I simply inflate the *booking_details* which is a simple View, containing a MapFragment.

The second time I click one of these rows, I get the exception mentioned above. Since the view is not a Fragment on its own (its just a View so far), I am not sure how to avoid this exception.

I have a vague idea to use FragmentManager, but Im not sure exactly how.

Can someone explain this to me perhaps?

Comment: you should really be using a `DialogFragment` to show your AlertDialog and not just creating a general alertdialog in your fragment

Comment: The thing is, I really dislike creating one class for each Dialog I want to use, when there is no need for it, really. Its much cleaner and leaner to just have a "popup" (AlertDialog in Android, MessageBox in C# etc), and place whatever controls u want inside that. To create a whole new class just to have a Dialog is so bloated I think...

Comment: The point is to create a "usercontrol" that can be placed "anywhere", not force it to become a "DialogFragment". Sometimes, maybe I dont want it as a dialog? The "usercontrol" should not know if it is in a Dialog or not, its just a "usercontrol" that can do certain things.